# How to display default and props values in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display default value="playlist" and when the user click it replace with default value, show the props values.
Right now its show the props value when i click the menu but i want to  show the playlist name there and then its switch the value/name with props when user click menu

```
 var defaultValue="playlist";

    return (
        <div className="mainContent">
            <div className="tableHeaderBody">
                <div className="TableText">{props.val}</div>  <div className="ClossIcon"><FaCircle style={{ color: "#FC0000", width: "10px", height: "10px", alignItems: "right" }} /></div>
            </div>           
        </div>
```

Comment: ``props || 'defaultvalue'``, maybe this can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the prop value as state, and setState when you call the onClick function.

```
const [playlist, setPlaylist] = useState("playlist");

    return (
        <div className="mainContent">
            <div className="tableHeaderBody">
                <div className="TableText">{playlist}</div>  <div className="ClossIcon"><FaCircle style={{ color: "#FC0000", width: "10px", height: "10px", alignItems: "right" }} /></div>
            </div>           
        </div>
```

And from wherever you call onCLick, define like this

```
OnClick={()=>setPlaylist(props.val)}
```